# Could not find i18n-0.6.9 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

Actually i'm getting that error inside the travis build.
My Gemfile is:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
# Gemfile for youtube_dlhelper
# Add dependencies required to use your gem here.
group :default do
gem 'highline'
gem 'dir'
gem 'fileutils2'
gem 'parseconfig'
gem 'viddl-rb'
gem 'streamio-ffmpeg'
gem 'rainbow'
gem 'gli'
end

# Add dependencies to develop your gem here.
# Include everything needed to run rake, tests, features, etc.
group :development do
  gem 'rdoc', '~> 4.1.0'
  gem 'bundler', '~> 1.0'
  gem 'jeweler', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'yard'
  gem 'gem-release'
end

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda', '>= 0'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'coveralls', require: false
  gem 'simplecov'
end
```

The Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    activesupport (4.0.2)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    addressable (2.3.5)
    atomic (1.1.14)
    builder (3.2.2)
    coveralls (0.7.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      rest-client
      simplecov (>= 0.7)
      term-ansicolor
      thor
    descendants_tracker (0.0.3)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    dir (0.1.2)
    docile (1.1.1)
    domain_name (0.5.15)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    faraday (0.8.8)
      multipart-post (~> 1.2.0)
    fileutils2 (0.2.0)
    gem-release (0.7.1)
    git (1.2.6)
    github_api (0.11.1)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
      descendants_tracker (~> 0.0.1)
      faraday (~> 0.8, < 0.10)
      hashie (>= 1.2)
      multi_json (>= 1.7.5, < 2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      oauth2
    gli (2.8.1)
    hashie (2.0.5)
    highline (1.6.20)
    http-cookie (1.0.2)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    httpauth (0.2.0)
    i18n (0.6.9)
    jeweler (2.0.0)
      builder
      bundler (>= 1.0)
      git (>= 1.2.5)
      github_api
      highline (>= 1.6.15)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.10)
      rake
      rdoc
    json (1.8.1)
    jwt (0.1.8)
      multi_json (>= 1.5)
    mechanize (2.7.3)
      domain_name (~> 0.5, >= 0.5.1)
      http-cookie (~> 1.0)
      mime-types (~> 2.0)
      net-http-digest_auth (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.1)
      net-http-persistent (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.2)
      nokogiri (~> 1.4)
      ntlm-http (~> 0.1, >= 0.1.1)
      webrobots (>= 0.0.9, < 0.2)
    mime-types (2.0)
    mini_portile (0.5.2)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    multi_json (1.8.2)
    multi_xml (0.5.5)
    multipart-post (1.2.0)
    net-http-digest_auth (1.4)
    net-http-persistent (2.9)
    nokogiri (1.6.1)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    ntlm-http (0.1.1)
    oauth2 (0.9.2)
      faraday (~> 0.8)
      httpauth (~> 0.2)
      jwt (~> 0.1.4)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (~> 1.2)
    parseconfig (1.0.4)
    progressbar (0.21.0)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rainbow (1.99.1)
    rake (10.1.1)
    rdoc (4.1.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rspec (2.14.1)
      rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
    rspec-core (2.14.7)
    rspec-expectations (2.14.4)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.14.4)
    shoulda (3.5.0)
      shoulda-context (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
      shoulda-matchers (>= 1.4.1, < 3.0)
    shoulda-context (1.1.6)
    shoulda-matchers (2.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    simplecov (0.8.2)
      docile (~> 1.1.0)
      multi_json
      simplecov-html (~> 0.8.0)
    simplecov-html (0.8.0)
    streamio-ffmpeg (1.0.0)
    term-ansicolor (1.2.2)
      tins (~> 0.8)
    thor (0.18.1)
    thread_safe (0.1.3)
      atomic
    tins (0.13.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.38)
    unf (0.1.3)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.6)
    viddl-rb (0.79)
      mechanize
      nokogiri
      progressbar
    webrobots (0.1.1)
    yard (0.8.7.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bundler (~> 1.0)
  coveralls
  dir
  fileutils2
  gem-release
  gli
  highline
  jeweler (~> 2.0.0)
  parseconfig
  rainbow
  rdoc (~> 4.1.0)
  rspec
  shoulda
  simplecov
  streamio-ffmpeg
  viddl-rb
  yard
```

I searched inside Stackoverflow and found mostly the answer to make a `bundle install` or remove the lock and bundle install again.
Also i tried out to use `bundle install -deployment` but that one uses all dependencies, and my *.gem is ~60M big (by using rake release).

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. The problem was, that i have overwritten the install section of .travis.yml. So `bundle install` aren't executed and it doesn't found it.

So the fix:
from

```
install:
  - sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras ffmpeg
```

to

```
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras ffmpeg
```